# pyodbc requires python 3.3

Tags: python, pyodbc

I just downloaded installer for pyodbc from [google project](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/list). I have Python 3.5 istalled and pyodbc requires 3.3. Is there an easy work around? 
P.S. I am installing it on PC without Internet access. This is for Windows.

Comment: Are you trying to install this on Windows, Linux or Mac (or other)?

Comment: Sorry, updated. This is for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't install this via the regular `pip` channels, you can download a prebuilt binary for Python 3.5 from [Chris Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc), where he has a bunch of libraries he creates builds for.

Download either depending on the version of Python 3.5 you have installed:

- `pyodbc‑3.0.10‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl` if you have a 32-bit Python 3.5 install
- `pyodbc‑3.0.10‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl` if you have a 64-bit Python 3.5 install

Get that file over to the computer you want to install on, and then install via `pip` on the command line:

```
pip install /path/to/whl/file
```

If you don't have `pip` in your `PATH`, it's usually located in:

```
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIRECTORY\scripts\pip.exe
```

Your install directory is probably `C:\Python35` unless you specified something different when you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite have the rep to comment so had to do it this way:

The @birryree answer worked on 64 bit Win 7 Enterprise SP1 but I got this ugly traceback which seems to be noise:

```
C:\Python\64-bit\Scripts>pip install \temp\python-wheels\uci.pyodbc-3.0.10-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\temp\python-wheels\uci.pyodbc-3.0.10-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: uci.pyodbc
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\64-bit\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python\64-bit\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\python\64-bit\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\python\64-bit\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\python\64-bit\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\python\64-bit\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 348, in move_wheel_files
    assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: uci.pyodbc==3.0.10 .dist-info directory not found
```

Note that I prepended the downloaded package with "uci." (since that is where Chris Gholkes site is hosted).

I know pyodbc was installed because I ran "pip list" before and after the install and got this:

```
    C:\Python\64-bit\Scripts>pip list
pip (8.1.2)
pyodbc (3.0.10)     <--- added by the install
pypyodbc (1.3.3)
setuptools (21.0.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

BTW, tested by porting (32-bit) Python 3.2.2 code to 64-bit 3.5.1. Win 7 Enterprise SP1 in both cases, no changes needed.