# Will the pyodbc library work for 64-bit Windows?

Tags: pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a database server from my 64-bit Windows client machines. I tried to connect with adodbapi and it failed.

Comment: In short, yes. [Try it](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started) and post a new question if you need help with a specific issue. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, if you're having problems getting `pyodbc` to work, please show your homework. :)

Comment: You can encounter issues on a 64-bit system if your Python build or applicable libraries are 32-bit. Check that your python, pyodbc, pywin32 (or adodbapi) are all 64 bit. May not be the core issue, but easy to rule out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyodbc (or pypyodbc) can do be used to set up the connection.

The accepted answer to [pyodbc requires python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045728/pyodbc-requires-python-3-3/) describes how to install pyodbc.  Also posted there is my experience (an exception was thrown) when using that method to successfully install 64-bit pyobdc for Python 3.5.1.on Win 7 Enterprise SP1.

Here's a summary of the method:

1 - Go to Chris Gholke's site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (which has Windows versions of many packages) and download the 64 bit pyodbc package (for 3.x: pyodbc-3.0.10-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl, 
for 2.7: pyodbc-3.0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl)

2 - Open a command line window and perform the remaining steps inside that window.

3 - Move (cd) to the Scripts folder located beneath your python installation folder.  In the posted example this was C:\python\64-bit\Scripts.

4 - Run pip to see what's already installed:

```
pip list
```

5 - If wheel is not listed you will need to install it before installing pyobdc:

```
pip install wheel
```

Which installs wheel directly off the web (you could download and install as per the next step)

6 - Use pip to install pyodbc:

```
pip install <path to your download folder>\pyodbc-3.0.10-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl  - change name for 2.7
```

7 - You may get an exception (documented with the example) but it doesn't seem to matter.  Confirm installation by entering:

```
pip list
```

8 - Use pyobdc.