# error while installing pyodbc 3.0.10 on python 3.3 using pip and easy_install

Tags: python, pip, pyodbc, easy-install

I am using windows 8.1 64-bit with python 3.3. I have tried to execute easy_install pyodbc and pip install pyodbc each got different errors like below:

easy_install pyodbc:

C:\Python33>easy_install pyodbc
Searching for pyodbc
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyodbc/
Best match: pyodbc 3.0.10
Downloading

```
Processing pyodbc-3.0.10.tar.gz

Writing c:\users\chaith~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-s1q95y\pyodbc-3.0.10\s etup.cfg Running pyodbc-3.0.10\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir



c:\users\chaith~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-s1q95y\pyodbc-3.0.10\egg-dist-tmp-onfjbk
```

**error: c:\users\chaith~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-s1q95y\pyodbc-3.0.10\py
odbc.egg-info\SOURCES.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is bein
g used by another process**

pip install pyodbc :

C:\Python33>pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-3.0.10.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyodbc

```
 Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Python33\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\chaith~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-8xaz3g
\\pyodbc\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read(
).replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\chaith~1\
appdata\local\temp\pip-xaf4bf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externa
lly-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).


----------------------------------------

 Command "C:\Python33\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
 tokenize;__file__='c:\
 \users\\chaith~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-8xaz3g\\pyodbc\\setup.py';exec
 (compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',
 open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),  __file__, 'exec'))"
 install --record c:\users\chaith~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-x
 af4bf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
 --compile" f ailed with error code 1 in c:\users\chaith~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-8xaz3g \pyodbc\
```

I have gone mad searching for the solutions. please help me it is very important for me to connect the sql server database with python

Comment: Either install the msvc compiler (and all other prerequisites).. or go pick up your ppyodbc here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc

Comment: Tried that already but, they haven't got windows binaries for python 3.3

Comment: Then you'll either need to upgrade your Python or install correct versions of the build-tools and required libraries (it's a pita on windows, but perfectly doable..)

Comment: I have done that but it is showing **pyodbc-3.0.10-cp34-none-win_amd64 (2).whl** is not a supported wheel on this platform. I am using 64 bit windows and python 3.4.2

Comment: You're on 64-bit Windows, but is your Python 32 or 64 bit? Just type `python` at the command line (does it say 'on win32'?). I believe Python's default download defaults to 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

The way @thebjorn suggests solves the problem.  More detail is found here: [pyodbc requires python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045728/pyodbc-requires-python-3-3/).  I just used that method an houror so ago to install 64 bit pyobdc 3.0.10 with python 3.5.1 (for use with pydev running under Eclipse Mars.2) on 64-bit Win 7 Enterprise SP 1.

I ran across a seemingly intimidating exception thrown by the install process (I've documented it in that question) but pyobdc works and pip says it's installed.

BTW, Python 3.5.1 can be installed on Win 7, etc. without admin rights once Microsoft patch KB2999226 has been applied (but that does need admin rights).

Comment: Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70796395/8614314