# Connection busy with results for another command, while MARS Connection is being used

Tags: python, sql-server, django

While trying to `dumpdata` in Django with the following command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --all --output /data/django_dump.json --verbosity 3
```

I get the following error:

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Connection is busy with results for another command (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
Exception ignored in: <generator object _cursor_iter at 0x7f1c4112b0c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/compiler.py", line 133, in _cursor_iter
    cursor.close()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 500, in close
    self.cursor.close()
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The cursor's connection has been closed.
```

[Following the advice of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770942/how-to-use-django-with-sql-server), here's my database configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': ...,
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': ...,
        'USER': ...,
        'PASSWORD': ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'MARS_Connection': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Using the MARS connection doesn't seem to help at all. Is my configuration wrong? Is there some other reason this might not work?

Python>=3.6, Django>=2, using MS SQL Server (not sure which version, nothing too old) and django-pyodbc-azure from conda-forge.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @prof.phython yeah, to not use SQL Server. I wish I could give better news, but at some point I just gave up trying to use MSSS with Python and switched to Postgres, and I don't think I figured this one out before making that switch.

Comment: Coming in _much_ later to this, but `'MARS_Connection': True` isn't technically correct (should be `'Yes'`), but this also never worked for me. I had to specify `'extra_params': 'MARS_Connection=Yes'`. Hope this helps someone

Comment: @WillGordon you helped me a lot. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

I tried around setting the MARS_Connection parameter and this is what finally worked (Django 3.0, django-mssql-backend 2.8.1) i.e. putting `'extra_params': 'MARS_Connection=Yes'` inside of the OPTIONS:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        },
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'extra_params': 'MARS_Connection=Yes'
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this solved a problem during a pretty long migration!